# What is the best way to maximize jupyterhub pods resources assignment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jupyterhub

We have an Openshift environment on our company.
We're trying to maximize the resources between our data scientists using jupyterhub.
Is there an option for assigning more resources **dynamicly** per demand (if there are free resources avaliable).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at setting resource restrictions. (Quite counterintuitive, I agree).

In Kubernetes (and therefore in OpenShift) you can set resource `requests` and `limits`.

Resource `requests` are the minimum a pod is guaranteed from the scheduler on the node it runs on. Resource `Limits` on the other hand give you the capability to allow your pod to exceed its requested resources up to the specified limit.

What is the difference between not setting resource `requests` and `limits` vs setting them?

#### Setting resource `requests` and `limits`

- scheduler is aware of resources utilized. New resources can be scheduled according to the resources they require.
- scheduler can rebalance pods across the nodes if a node hits maximum resource utilization
- pods can not exceed the `limits` specified
- pods are guaranteed to get at least the resources specified in `requests`

#### **NOT** setting resource `requests` and `limits`

- scheduler is aware of resources utilized. New resources (e.g. pods) can be scheduled based on a best guess basis. It is not guaranteed that those new pods get minimum resources they require to run stable.
- scheduler is not able to rebalance resources without at least `requests`
- pods can utilize memory / cpu without restrictions
- pods are not guaranteed any memory / cpu time

---

### How to set up resource `requests` and `limits`

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/compute_resources.html

In the end it should look something like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: openshift/hello-openshift
    name: hello-openshift
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m 
        memory: 200Mi 
        ephemeral-storage: 1Gi 
      limits:
        cpu: 200m 
        memory: 400Mi 
        ephemeral-storage: 2Gi
```

---

Additional information can be found here

- https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell if those resource allocation can occur while a container is already running and?

Comment: Hi AS IL, a running container is static in its configuration. If you want to add e.g. requests/quotas you will have to redeploy your pods (Kubernetes/OpenShift scheduling unit for containers). I recommend that you add the resource quotas to any new resource that get's deployed and after a while you can enforce quotas. e.g. no resource can be scheduled if it does not specify how much resources it is going to consume.